# How to create multiple Oracle databases on one AWS RDS instance?

Tags: oracle11g, amazon-rds

How can I create multiple databases on one Oracle RDS instance on AWS? How does it work e.g. with sqlplus on the CLI?

Comment: Have you tried the [`CREATE DATABASE` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/create003.htm#ADMIN11073)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work simply like `CREATE DATABASE abcd`, there's obviously more to it.

Comment: Could you please expand on your question by clarifying what you are doing (code samples encouraged!) and what errors you are receiving.